# R Create a closure counter

Tags: r, xml-parsing, closures, sax

I am totally out of my depth on this. I am trying to read a large xml file using closure functions. The only issue is, I am unable to figure out a way to create a counter within the closure, so that I can use the counter as an id for the store location. I have come up with the following code which has obviously some (or maybe serious) issues.

```
branchFunction <- function() {
  store <- new.env() 
  func <- function(x, ...) {
    new_counter <- function() {
      i <- 0
      function() {
        i <<- i + 1
        i
      }
    }
    ns <- getNodeSet(x,path = "//event[@type='left link' or @type='entered link']")
    value <- lapply(ns, xmlAttrs)
    store[[i]] <- value
  }
  getStore <- function() { as.list( store ) }
  list(event = func, getStore=getStore)
}

myfunctions <- branchFunction()

xmlEventParse(file = "xml.xml", handlers = NULL, branches = myfunctions)

#to see what is inside
l <- myfunctions$getStore()
```

Here is the sample [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4u0mlpdrctyvhk9/xml.xml?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is pretty much it, you just want to call the function to get it going,

```
new_counter <- (function() {
  i <- 0
  function() { 
    i <<- i + 1
    i
  }
})()
```

Comment: Doing this is giving me the error `Error in store[[i]] <- value : object 'i' not found
Called from: (function (x, ...) 
{
    new_counter <- (function() {
        i <- 0
        function() {
            i <<- i + 1
            i
        }
    })()
    ns <- getNodeSet(x, path = "//event[@type='left link' or @type='entered link']")
    value <- lapply(ns, xmlAttrs)
    store[[i]] <- value
})(<pointer: 0x0000000016af3f40>)`

Comment: Along with your above fix, does this make any sense?
`store[[new_counter()]] <- value`

Comment: Now, this is giving me a new error: `Error in store[[new_counter()]] <- value : wrong args for environment subassignment`

Comment: Duh...Thanks for that. Just want to let you know that the counter keeps on repeating the value 1 if it is placed in the function `func`. It works properly if it is above `func` and below the `branchfunction` like this: 
`branchFunction <- function() {
  store <- new.env() 
  new_counter <- (function() {
    i <- 0
    function() { 
      i <<- i + 1
      i
    }
  })()
  func <- function(x, ...) {
    ns <- getNodeSet(x,path = "//event[@type='left link' or @type='entered link']")
    value <- lapply(ns, xmlAttrs)
     store[[toString(new_counter())]] <- value
  }
## rest is same`